# VBA: .Refresh Run-Time Error

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a problem with some VBA code.  I'm running Excel 2010 on Windows 7 Enterprise.

I'm trying to read in several tab-delimited text files from a folder and put them onto separate sheets in one Excel workbook.  To do this, I'm using a Query Table.  In debugging, I have a problem with `.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False`.  When it reaches this line, it throws a 1004 run-time error, stating that Excel cannot find the text file to refresh this external data range.  I don't know why this is occurring.  I know that the Query Table isn't created until it reads this line, which makes debugging difficult.  Here is the code.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

```
Sub LoadPipeDelimitedFiles()
Dim idx As Integer
Dim fname As String

idx = 0
fname = Dir("C:\files\*.txt")
While (Len(fname) > 0)
    idx = idx + 1
    Sheets("Sheet" & idx).Select
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & fname, Destination:=Range("A1"))
        .Name = "a" & idx
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileOtherDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        fname = Dir
    End With
Wend
End Sub
```

Here is the correction:

```
Sub LoadPipeDelimitedFiles()
Dim idx As Integer
Dim fpath As String
Dim fname As String
Dim f_dummy As String

idx = 0
fpath = "C:\files\"
f_dummy = fpath & "*.txt"
fname = Dir(f_dummy)
While (Len(fname) > 0)
    idx = idx + 1
    Sheets("Sheet" & idx).Select
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" _
      & fpath & fname, Destination:=Range("A1"))
        .Name = "a" & idx
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileOtherDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        fname = Dir
    End With
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Based on your correction, it culminates to what I said in my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Change the line `With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & fname, Destination:=Range("A1"))`

to

`With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & "C:\files\" & fname, Destination:=Range("A1"))`

You `fname` just has the name of the file and not the full path

Also avoid using `.Select` and fully qualify your `Objects`. 
[INTERESTING READ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Your code can be written as

```
Sub LoadPipeDelimitedFiles()
    Dim idx As Integer
    Dim fname As String, FullName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    idx = 0

    fname = Dir("C:\*.txt")

    While (Len(fname) > 0)
        FullName = "C:\" & fname
        idx = idx + 1

        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet" & idx)

        With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & _
        FullName, Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
            '
            '~~> Rest of the code
            '
            fname = Dir
        End With
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  That did the trick.  Actually, what caused this problem in the first place is that I had left off the last slash character at the end of my path.  I will update this post with my full code to show what it looks like now.

Comment: No don't update my post :) you can explain that by updating your question